# Akeneo-labs spreadsheet-parser, how to read first row only?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, spreadsheet, akeneo

I would like to read first row without [createRowIterato](https://github.com/akeneo-labs/spreadsheet-parser) interface as first line, in XLSX file, belongs to my database table fields. So I would like to read them first and want to put it in fields array.

I am using sample code at first level:

```
$workbook = SpreadsheetParser::open('myfile.xlsx');
$myWorksheetIndex = $workbook->getWorksheetIndex('sheet1');

//MY REQUIREMENT
//Here I want to get first row as they will be treated as my table fields.

foreach ($workbook->createRowIterator($myWorksheetIndex) as $rowIndex => $values) {
    var_dump($rowIndex, $values);
}
```

Any help would be great.